# Custom messagebox doesnot return any value in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, signals-slots

from my previous question i knew how to connect child to parent inside thread in main application.
but my messagebox suppose to return value when button press and and wait parent till child closed.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QApplication,QWidget,QPushButton,QDialog,QFrame,QLabel,QTextEdit
from threading import Thread
import threading
import time


class messagebox(QObject):
    speak_word = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent=parent
        #self.speak_word = pyqtSignal(str)
        
        self.parent_width=self.parent.geometry().width()
        self.parent_height=self.parent.geometry().height()
        self.speak_word.connect(self.sayHelloFromMainThread)
    #This method will flash the messagebox dialog when we click on parent
    def flash(self,event):
                    QTimer.singleShot(50,lambda:self.toolbar.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue;\n"
        "border-top-left-radius: 20px;\n"
        "border-top-right-radius: 20px;\n"
        "") )
                    QTimer.singleShot(120, lambda:self.toolbar.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;\n"
        "border-top-left-radius: 20px;\n"
        "border-top-right-radius: 20px;\n"
        "") )

    def sayHelloFromMainThread(self):
         self.showinfo('hello','how r u?')
    def hellor(self):
        self.speak_word.emit('hi')
    def showinfo(self,title="ShowInfo",msg="Hello,There!"):
        self.value=None
        self.pop = QDialog()
        self.pop.setGeometry(500,200,454,165)
        self.msg=msg
        self.pop.mousePressEvent=self.click
        self.pop.mouseMoveEvent=self.move
        self.frame = QFrame(self.pop)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: #1b1b1b;\n"
            "border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;\n"
            "border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;\n"
            "")
        self.frame.setGeometry(0,30,454,134)
        self.toolbar = QFrame(self.pop)
        self.toolbar.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;\n"
            "border-top-left-radius: 20px;\n"
            "border-top-right-radius: 20px;\n"
            "")
        self.toolbar.setGeometry(0,0,454,30)
        #This makes the window to frameless
        self.pop.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint|Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.pop.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        #self.cover will Cover a frame to its parent entirely
        self.cover=QFrame(self.parent)
        self.cover.resize(self.parent_width,self.parent_height)
        self.cover.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;")
        #you can see the frame by setting background to a color
        self.cover.show()
        self.cover.mousePressEvent=self.flash
        b1 = QPushButton("Ok",self.frame)
        b1.setStyleSheet('''QPushButton {background-color: red;
        border-style: outset;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border-color: beige;
        font: bold 14px;
        min-width: 60px;
        min-height: 25px;
        }''''''QPushButton:pressed{background-color: green;
        border-style: inset;}''')
        b1.move(350,100)
        b1.clicked.connect(self.on_close)
        self.pop.setWindowTitle("Dialog")
        self.pop.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModal)
        self.pop.exec_()
        return self.value
    def on_close(self):
        self.value=True
        self.cover.deleteLater()
        self.pop.close()
    # move and click  methods are used to drag the dialog
    def move(self, event):
            if event.buttons() ==Qt.LeftButton:
                    deltax = event.x()- self.xp
                    deltay = event.y() - self.yp
                    x = self.pop.x() + deltax
                    y = self.pop.y() + deltay
                    width,height=int(self.pop.geometry().width()),int(self.pop.geometry().height())
                    self.pop.setGeometry(int(x),int(y),width,height)
    def click(self, event):
           if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
               self.xp=event.x()
               self.yp=event.y()


def window():
       app = QApplication(sys.argv)
       w = QWidget()
       w.setGeometry(100,100,400,400)
       b = QPushButton(w)
       b.setText("Hello World!")
       b.move(50,50)
       ui = messagebox(w)
       def dowork():
            h=ui.hellor()
            print(h)
       def run():
               Thread(target=dowork).start()
       b.clicked.connect(run)
       w.setWindowTitle("PyQt Dialog demo")
       w.show()
       sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

without calling from thread it makes parent wait but i dont know how to return value suppose true or false by button click.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are still confusing what should go to the thread and what should not. Also, you're not using QThread as already explained, which is mandatory if you need to communicate between threads. Finally, you're using `h=ui.hellor()`, but `hellor()` doesn't return anything. You must create a QThread subclass and use custom signals to communicate with it. Please, read and try to understand the previous answer given to you, then post a comment there if something is not clear, specifying *what* is not clear.

Comment: yes QThread wroks perfectly.